# Select index Array with Drag & Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Good Day, I have this HTML:

```
<ul class="sortable-list" style="list-style-type: none;"></ul>
```

and this Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var old, manip;

  function Person(id, first, last, age, eyecolor) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
  }

  Person.prototype.display = function() {
    sortableList.push(this);

    $(".sortable-list").sortable({
      axis: "y",
      containment: ".sortable-list",
      revert: true,

      start: function(event, ui) {
        var updt = ui.item.index();
        manip = updt;
        old = sortableList[manip];
      },

      update: function(event, ui) {
        var newIndex = ui.item.index();
        sortableList.splice(manip, 1);
        sortableList.splice(newIndex, 0, old);
      }

    });

    var moveMe = "<i class='fa fa-arrows-v' aria-hidden='true' style='border:1px solid black;padding:5px;background-color:#91DAF2;'></i>";
    var seeDetails = "<i class='fa fa-eye' aria-hidden='true' style='border:1px solid black;padding:5px;background-color:#F5940C;' onclick='seeDetails(" + this.id + ");'></i>";

    var fNameObj = "<input type='text' value=" + this.firstName + " size='7' style='font-size:13px;' disabled=true>";
    var lNameObj = "<input type='text' value=" + this.lastName + " size='7' style='font-size:13px;' disabled=true>";
    var ageObj = "<input type='text' value=" + this.age + " size='3' style='font-size:13px;' disabled=true>";

    var output = "<li>" + moveMe + " " + seeDetails + " " + fNameObj + " " + lNameObj + " " + ageObj + "</li>";

    $(".sortable-list").append(output);
  };

  var me = new Person(1, "John", "Doe", 22, "blue");
  me.display();

  var you = new Person(2, "Jane", "Smith", 33, "green");
  you.display();

  var him = new Person(3, "Mike", "Jones", 44, "brown");
  him.display();

  var her = new Person(4, "Gill", "Greer", 55, "green");
  her.display();

  var us = new Person(5, "Paul", "Mall", 66, "blue");
  us.display();

});



var sortableList = [];

function seeDetails(index) {
  var temp = sortableList[index - 1];
  alert(temp.firstName + " " + temp.lastName + " has " + temp.eyeColor + " eyes.");
  console.log(sortableList);
}
```

I use FontAwesome to display the icons for the buttons.
What I try to do is to display the content of the object by passing the id to the function `seeDetails`.
I'd like to keep track of the elements order, because I'll use it further in my code.
Is there any way to use that code to display the proper content of the object, after drag&drop ? Anybody can help ? Thanks!
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ericfourmaux/ah2qfbu7/)

Comment: Anybody can help ?? :(

Comment: Need more info ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sortable has 2 methods that may help: `serialize` and `toArray`

**serialize**

> Serializes the sortable's item `id`s into a form/ajax submittable string. Calling this method produces a hash that can be appended to any url to easily submit a new item order back to the server.
>
> It works by default by looking at the `id` of each item in the format `"setname_number"`, and it spits out a hash like `"setname[]=number&setname[]=number"`.

See more: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize

**toArray**

> Serializes the sortable's item id's into an array of string.

See More: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray

Depending on how you want to use the order later, one of these methods will help you. I suspect you will want to pass this data into a variable in `update` or `stop` callback.

To ensure these work better, you would want to add an `id` attribute to opit list items. For example:

```
var output = "<li id='person-" + this.id + "'>" + moveMe + " " + seeDetails + " " + fNameObj + " " + lNameObj + " " + ageObj + "</li>";
```

What I noticed is that we're passing back an index to `seeDetails()`, when you can also pass back the `id` for that person. Consider this:

```
function seeDetails(i) {
  var temp;
  $.each(sortableList, function(k, p) {
    if (p.id == i) {
      temp = p;
    }
  });
  console.log(temp.firstName, temp.lastName, "has", temp.eyeColor, "eyes.");
}
```

Putting it all together, here is what I would advise: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Lyotc8d5/

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var old, manip;

  function Person(id, first, last, age, eyecolor) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
  }

  Person.prototype.display = function() {
    sortableList.push(this);

    var that = this;

    $(".sortable-list").sortable({
      axis: "y",
      containment: ".sortable-list",
      revert: true,
      start: function(event, ui) {
        var updt = ui.item.index();
        manip = updt;
        old = sortableList[manip];
      },
      update: function(event, ui) {
        var newIndex = ui.item.index();
        sortableList.splice(manip, 1);
        sortableList.splice(newIndex, 0, old);
      }
    });

    var moveMe = $("<i>", {
      class: 'fa fa-arrows-v',
      "aria-hidden": true,
      style: 'border:1px solid black;padding:5px;background-color:#91DAF2;'
    });

    var detailsBtn = $("<i>", {
      class: 'fa fa-eye',
      "aria-hidden": true,
      style: 'border:1px solid black;padding:5px;background-color:#F5940C;'
    }).click(function(e) {
      seeDetails(that.id);
    });

    var fNameObj = $("<input>", {
      type: 'text',
      value: that.firstName,
      size: 7,
      style: 'font-size:13px;',
      disabled: true
    });

    var lNameObj = $("<input>", {
      type: 'text',
      value: that.lastName,
      size: 7,
      style: 'font-size:13px;',
      disabled: true
    });

    var ageObj = $("<input>", {
      type: 'text',
      value: this.age,
      size: 3,
      style: 'font-size:13px;',
      disabled: true
    });

    var output = $("<li>", {
      id: 'person-' + that.id
    });

    output.append(moveMe, detailsBtn, fNameObj, lNameObj, ageObj);
    $(".sortable-list").append(output);
  };

  var me = new Person(1, "John", "Doe", 22, "blue");
  me.display();

  var you = new Person(2, "Jane", "Smith", 33, "green");
  you.display();

  var him = new Person(3, "Mike", "Jones", 44, "brown");
  him.display();

  var her = new Person(4, "Gill", "Greer", 55, "green");
  her.display();

  var us = new Person(5, "Paul", "Mall", 66, "blue");
  us.display();
});

var sortableList = [];

function seeDetails(i) {
  var temp;
  $.each(sortableList, function(k, p) {
    if (p.id == i) {
      temp = p;
    }
  });
  console.log(temp.firstName, temp.lastName, "has", temp.eyeColor, "eyes.");
}
```

A few small updates. Not that your code was wrong or incorrect, I just like creating the jQuery objects and find them easier to work with. Assigning `this` to variable `that` is helpful to ensure there is no confusion around `this` in other functions, like for `click` callback.